# SQL Query join in multiple instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to join the below two table using SQL Query:
table 1

```
  Taxid  sal_cd 
   1000.  A01
   1000.  B01
   2000.  C01
   3000.  D01
   4000.   Null
```

Table 2:

```
    OrderCode amt  sal_cd
     201.     20.   A01
     202.     30.   B01
     202.     10.   C01
     203.      5.   D01
```

result I want like below:

```
Taxis. Ordercode. Amt
1000.   201.       20
1000.   202.       30
1000.   203.        0
2000.   201.        0
2000.   202.        10
2000.   202.        0
3000.   201.        0
3000.   202.        0
3000.   203.        5
4000.   201.        0
4000.   202.        0
4000.    203.       0
```

Help me to get the above result using SQL Query
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your above data correct?

Comment: The `2000. 202. 0` line is particularly troubling

Comment: I want data to get all the ordercode and taxid from both table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to proceed as if 2000/202/0 is a typo that should be 203

We need the thousands and hundreds numbers repeating:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Taxid, Ordercode
FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2
```

Then we need to left join to this data set with the real data, given by this:

```
SELECT t1.Taxid, t2.OrderCode, t2.Amt 
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.sal_cd = t2.sal_cd
```

Resulting in:

```
SELECT all.Taxid as Taxid, all.OrderCode, COALESCE(some.Amt, 0) as Amt
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT t1.Taxid, t2.Ordercode
  FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2
) all
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT t1.Taxid, t2.OrderCode, t2.Amt 
  FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.sal_cd = t2.sal_cd
)
ON
  all.Taxid = some.taxid AND
  all.Ordercode = some.Ordercode
```

I've aliased the output as Taxis even though I think that, also, is a typo

Comment: realised that I reached the same [solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=13b78c83e5d918d7e8218a0245b3f481) with a great latency :) +1

Answer (score 0):

**Table 1:**

[image: table1]

**Table 2:**

[image: table2]

**Final query:**

```
Select t1.taxid, t2.OrderCode, t2.Amt
FROM t1  
CROSS JOIN t2
GROUP BY taxid,OrderCode
ORDER BY t1.taxid
```

**Final result:**

[image: resultset]

Answer (score -1):

```
Select t1.Taxis, t2.OrderCode, t2.Amt
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.sal_cd = t2.sal_cd
ORDER BY t1.Taxis
```

Note: This will not give your expected output. It will give the output of the matches on sal_cd though, if that is what you're after.

Comment: this is will not provide the expected result

Comment: Doesn't give the requested output

Comment: It doesn't give expected result.